# Solve for $x(t)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have
$\frac{dx}{dt} = -x^3$, with condition $x(0) = 10$. When solving for $x(t)$,
$\frac{x^{-2}}{-2} = -t - C$, after solving for $C$ using the initial condition it leads to $x(t) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2t}}$, which doesn't satisfy the condition $x(0) = 10$.
Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $C=\dfrac1{200},$ so $x(t)=\sqrt{\dfrac1{2t+\frac1{100}}}=\dfrac{10}{\sqrt{200t+1}}.$

Answer (score 3):

By separation of variables you have
$$\frac{dx}{x^3} = -dt,$$
and integrating 
$$\int_{10}^{x(t)} \frac{dy}{y^3} = -\int_0^t ds \Rightarrow -\frac12 \left(\frac{1}{x(t)^2}-\frac{1}{10^2}\right) = -t.$$
This leads to $1/x(t)^2 = 2t+1/100$, namely $x(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+1/100}}$.